# Question may be about programming or math. Where to ask?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

During software development, I have encountered a problem that seems to be rather mathematical in nature: The solution may be a simple formula. But there is also a good chance that there is no such formula, and the solution is actually an algorithm.

Now, I do not know where to ask about the problem:

- stackoverflow.com?
- math.stackexchange.com?
- programmers.stackexchange.com?
- cross-post, each question specifically tailored to each site? (I understand, this is generally frowned upon)

Comment: If it's a _concrete_ programming problem whose solution involves math than it is _perfertly_ fine to ask about it in StackOverflow.

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Comment: Can you solve your problem on pencil and paper?  If no, and you're trying to figure out how to get the answer in general, it wouldn't be on topic on SO.  If you know how to get the answer but don't know how to implement it in a programming language, *then* it would possibly be an SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend asking your question on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).  There is an [algorithm tag on that site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms).  It seems to be suited more towards Mathematics than Stack Overflow because you say that the problem is "mathematical in nature", and the solution as a formula or an algorithm exists apart from any programming solution.  The Programmers site is more about questions as a programmer before any code is written.  Only when the question would be about implementing that algorithm or formula in code would that be more suitable for Stack Overflow.